# AsyncTask in onCreate method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have a simple application that plays online radio. for showing the title from online php service i use AsyncTask and call it from onCreate method. in android 4 everythin is OK, but in android 2 it's crushed with error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

then in internet i found, that i must use a code like

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //my code
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

but after i using this tip, a can't see any button and text views in my android 4 and android 2 versions. this is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //thread for update title every second
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            new ShowTitle()
                                .execute("http://info.radiostyle.ru/inc/getinfo.php?getcurentsong=20383&mount=lezgifm");
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            String tag = "Update title";
                            Log.e(tag, "Update title crashed", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

 //get title string from online source
private String getMusicTitle(String url) {
    Document doc = null;
    String title = "Music Title";
    try {
        url = "http://info.radiostyle.ru/inc/getinfo.php?getcurentsong=20383&mount=lezgifm";
        InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "CP1251", url);
        title = doc.body().text();//doc.select(".products_name").first().text();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return title;
}

//class for show the audio title
private class ShowTitle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return getMusicTitle(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        lblMusicName.setText(result);
    }

}
```

EDIT: (my working code)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new ShowTitle()
        .execute("http://info.radiostyle.ru/inc/getinfo.php?getcurentsong=20383&mount=lezgifm");
}

private String getMusicTitle(String url) {
    Document doc = null;
    String title = "Music Title";
    try {
        url = "http://info.radiostyle.ru/inc/getinfo.php?getcurentsong=20383&mount=lezgifm";
        InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "CP1251", url);
        title = doc.body().text();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
        title = "Failed to load title";
    }
    return title;
}

private class ShowTitle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        while (true) {
            String str = getMusicTitle(urls[0]);
            publishProgress(str);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                String tag = "Update title";
                Log.e(tag, "Update title crashed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... result) {
        lblMusicName.setText(result[0]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runOnUiThread` and `AsyncTask` are two different things. You are using it in a wrong way.

Try it like this:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            new ShowTitle().execute("http://info.radiostyle.ru/inc/getinfo.php?getcurentsong=20383&mount=lezgifm");
        }

 //get title string from online source
private String getMusicTitle(String url) {
    Document doc = null;
    String title = "Music Title";
    try {
        url = "http://info.radiostyle.ru/inc/getinfo.php?getcurentsong=20383&mount=lezgifm";
        InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "CP1251", url);
        title = doc.body().text();//doc.select(".products_name").first().text();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
        title = "Failed to load title";

    }
    return title;
}

//class for show the audio title
private class ShowTitle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String str = getMusicTitle(urls[0]);
        while(true) {
           publishProgress(str);
           try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        String tag = "Update title";
                        Log.e(tag, "Update title crashed", e);
                    }
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        if(returnVal.startsWith("Failed")) {
             Toast.makeText(this, returnVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
             lblMusicName.setText(result);
        }
    }


}
```

You must do all the UI related task in `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: lblMusicName must be updatable every second and i don't need Toast. the main issue to get updateble lblMusicName, thats why i use Thread in onCreate method with while(true)

Comment: check this line.. **private class ShowTitle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {** ..hav u changed it?

Comment: add a break point in getMusicTitle and check if u r getting a title or is der any exception.

Comment: in my first run I get the title, but it's not update every second as I want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30330/discussion-between-jack-daniel-and-bakrionfire)

Comment: i just put String str = getMusicTitle(urls[0]); inside the while. thx, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

In here :

```
 try {
       //....your code here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load HTML code", e);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load title", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //<<< this line
    }
```

you are trying to show Toast Message from `doInBackground` (from non-ui Thread). use `onPostExecute` for showing Toast Message or updating UI according to result returned from  doInBackground

and second issue is here:

```
while(true) {
  try {
        ...
      Thread.sleep(1000); //<<< here calling Thread.sleep on Main UI Thread
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      String tag = "Update title";
      Log.e(tag, "Update title crashed", e);
 }
```

this will always freeze Ui Thread for after  AsyncTask execution . so will need to move `Thread.sleep(1000)` outside `runOnUiThread` code block

Comment: i dont't need the Toast and i deleted it from code and move Thread.sleep() from runOnUiThread to the main Thread. but nothing was changed

Comment: @JackDaniel : what do u mean nothing was changed? plz also update your question with latest code and my one more suggestion is also remove while loop which you are using for executing  AsyncTask